# Telegraf/Influxdb URL issue

Tags: url, influxdb, telegraf

I tried and tried to get my telegraf to write to my db server urls = ["192.168.0.212:8086"] but it didn't work.  The DB server is configured correctly since it is already receiving telegraf data, though from itself (localhost).  After i installed and configured influx on the local host, I then tried to the local host using its url urls = ["192.168.0.214:8086"] but no go.  when i tried local host urls = ["localhost:8086"] it worked fine.  SSH works OK and the router indicates static.  i also limited the dhcp range so that these ips cannot be used.  Am i missing something?  I have looked all over and i think the format is fine.

Please let me know.

Comment: For more information, the speed test server 214 is a pi zero w and the db server 212 is a pi 4 4G with an external 240gb SSD.  I successfully send speed test data from the 214 server to the database server 212.  Therefore, both servers are fine as is the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem and I found the firewall in the influxdb server was blocking port 8086.

In Ubuntu:

- check which ports are open: `sudo ufw status`
- if port `8086` is not enabled: `sudo ufw allow 8086`